# UIAlertView animation lag when shown

Tags: ios, animation, uialertview, lag

I am experiencing an odd lag in the animation whenever I display a `UIAlertView`. The buttons and labels on the alert view are appearing noticeably before the background. It is happening everywhere in the application that I display an alert

[image: alert view lag]

The alert in the example above is shown from the action method of the clear button:

```
-(IBAction)clearButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear Outbox" message:@"This will delete everything from your Outbox." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];   
    [alert show];
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening / what I can do to stop it?

Comment: Do you have any overlay view on the top of your UIViewController? Or other loading classes such as MBProgressHUD?

Comment: Nope nothing like that

Comment: hm.... then it is strange. Can you upload a sample project on Github? The problem is probably not on UIAlertView.

Comment: Do You have some complex background processes running? I noticed, that , if do "hardcore" background tasks (in fact - multiple such tasks) - it started lagging mainThread.

Comment: Hey but this is simulator, do You have the same problem on a real device as well?

Comment: This is on a real device (i'm recording the screen with http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "renders with edge antialiasing" to NO in the info.plist

Comment: Not sure how this got set as it defaults to NO. Any idea Liam?

Comment: I'm presuming a developer who didn't really know what it does must have set it on your project in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[yourAlert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: The show method is already being called on the main thread. Tried the above anyway to make sure, but it didn't make a difference.